# Change span icon onClick and move sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal scrolling website, and as the vertical scroll translates to horizontal, I've decided to add radio-style buttons to a fixed bottom navigation bar.

The trouble I'm having is that I want to switch out the span icon from an 'on' to an 'off'. I thought it would be easy enough to toggle the classes but I'm struggling with it.

The radio icons are not showing on this example for some reason, but I am trying to change `radio-button-off` to `radio-button-on` when I click on the `span`.

Sorry if this has been asked before, I had a look around but couldn't find anything which worked for me. I want to link these up to a smooth scroll afterwards, but I think I understand how to achieve that already.

An example of what I am slightly trying to achieve is the Small Dot Stroke here: https://tympanus.net/Development/DotNavigationStyles/

Heres what I have so far:

```js
// first try

//$('.bottomnav').click(function ({
  //          $(this).find('span').removeClass('ion-ios-radio-button-off');
    //        $(this).find('span').addClass('ion-ios-radio-button-on');
      //  });
      
      // second try
        
  //     $('.bottomnav a').click(function ({
//            $(this).find('span').removeClass('ion-ios-radio-button-off').addClass('ion-ios-radio-button-on');
 //       });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bottomnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bottomnav span {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
}

.bottomnav span:hover {
    color: white;
}

.bottomnav span.active {
    color: white;
}

#container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#container .card {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

#player {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    /*        position: absolute;*/
}

#player section > object {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


section object > div {
    white-space: normal;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

section {
      padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.cardwhite {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.cardblack {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Serif', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
 

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <div class="bottomnav">
            <a href="#header"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-on active"></span></a>
            <a href="#about"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
            <a href="#overview"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
            <a href="#web"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
            <a href="#drone"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
            <a href="#studio"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
            <a href="#portfolio"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
            <a href="#contact"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off"></span></a>
        </div>

<div class="container" id="container">
        <div id="player">
       <section class="card cardwhite" id="1">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 1</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                  
                </object>
            </section>

    <section class="card cardblack" id="2">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 2</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    
                </object>
            </section>

    <section class="card cardwhite" id="3">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 3</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                 
                </object>
            </section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried to simulate your issue in codepen. are you looking for something like this https://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/RXKYrO

Comment: Are you looking to toggle all radios, or are you looking to toggle only the radio which was clicked to on, and all others to off?

Comment: Yes something like that @krish :)

Comment: Only the radio which is clicked on @OliverRadini. These will correspond with the section which is in view.. hopefully.

Comment: @CaitlinMooney Ok, answer updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust classes using just javascript, and sometimes this is easier than trying to do the same with jquery:

```js
const setIconState = (icon, state) => icon.className = state
    ? icon.className.replace('button-off', 'button-on')
    : icon.className.replace('button-on', 'button-off')

const toggleIcon = element => {
  const className = element.className;
  element.className = className.indexOf('button-on') > -1
    ? setIconState(element, false)
    : setIconState(element, true);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.bottomnav span.icon')
  .forEach(icon => {
    icon.onclick = (e) => {
      const {
        target: clickedSpan
      } = e;
      
      const siblings = [...clickedSpan.parentElement.querySelectorAll('span.icon')]
        .filter(sibling => sibling != clickedSpan);

      siblings.forEach(icon => setIconState(icon, false));
      setIconState(clickedSpan, true);
    };
  })
```

```css
.bottomnav {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(220, 240, 250);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bottomnav">
  <span class="icon ion-android-radio-button-on active"></span>
  <span class="icon ion-android-radio-button-off"></span>
  <span class="icon ion-android-radio-button-off"></span>
</div>

<span class="icon ion-android-radio-button-off"></span>
```

Comment: I think I must be doing something wrong, as the span is wrapped in an <a> tag, I think theres an issue getting beyond the `bottomnav` element.

Comment: @CaitlinMooney I've updated the answer to include a selector which only adjusts those icons in the `bottomnav`, if that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: Your snippet is exactly what I am trying to achieve but not working for me at all, I think maybe due to the `<a>` tags surrounding my `span`, but they need to be there. Heres a codepen: https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/eqgKGo

Comment: It works in the codepen but the class doesn't remove, not working in my full project though, unsure why as of yet. But a massive help!

Comment: @CaitlinMooney Thanks, that pen helps; the problem is that my code was looking for just the `parentElement`, whereas the div it needed was two levels up, so `.parentElement.parentElement` is needed. You should be able to see it working here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mNRvdP

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much, I will make some notes for future reference!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you

```js
$('.bottomnav').click(function (e){
  if($(e.target).hasClass('ion-ios-radio-button-off')){
    $('span').addClass('ion-ios-radio-button-off');
    $('span').removeClass('ion-ios-radio-button-on');
    $(e.target).toggleClass('ion-ios-radio-button-off');
    $(e.target).toggleClass('ion-ios-radio-button-on');
 //   $(e.target).parent().trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bottomnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;'
    
}

.bottomnav a span {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
}

.bottomnav span:hover {
    color: white;
}

.bottomnav span.active {
    color: white;
}

#container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#container .card {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

#player {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    /*        position: absolute;*/
}

#player section > object {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


section object > div {
    white-space: normal;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

section {
      padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.cardwhite {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.cardblack {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Serif', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
.ion-ios-radio-button-off{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  
}
.ion-ios-radio-button-on{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  
}
.circle {
  border: 1px solid #D47474;
}
.ion-ios-radio-button-on.circle:before {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #D47474;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 0.2s fillin ease forwards;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

@keyframes fillin {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    background-color: #D47474;
  }
  100% {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #D47474;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/codrops/adpacks/demoad.css?1564409193439">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottomnav">
            <a href="#1"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-on active circle"></span></a>
            <a href="#2"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off circle"></span></a>
            <a href="#3"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off circle"></span></a>
            <a href="#web"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off circle"></span></a>
            <a href="#drone"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off circle"></span></a>
            <a href="#studio"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off circle"></span></a>
            <a href="#portfolio"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off circle"></span></a>
            <a href="#contact"><span class="icon ion-ios-radio-button-off circle"></span></a>
        </div>

<div class="container" id="container">
        <div id="player">
       <section class="card cardwhite" id="1">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 1</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                  
                </object>
            </section>

    <section class="card cardblack" id="2">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 2</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    
                </object>
            </section>

    <section class="card cardwhite" id="3">
                <object>
                        <h2>Section 3</h2>
                        <p>Description</p>
                 
                </object>
            </section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know what, its not exactly what I wanted but it just might work! Neve thought to try that way.

Comment: please explain exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I rather like this! It will be very useful to me, I will make notes for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the code written below is executed before the jQuery library is loaded.

```
$(".bottomnav").click(function(event) {
   $(this).find('span').removeClass('ion-ios-radio-button-off');
   $(this).find('span').addClass('ion-ios-radio-button-on');
});
```

This could be solved by writing this code inside ready event as below:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $(".bottomnav").click(function(event) {
        $(this).find('span').removeClass('ion-ios-radio-button-off');
        $(this).find('span').addClass('ion-ios-radio-button-on');
    });
});
```

I have tried this one in my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-swartz-huqkx). I have given text in your span so that they would be visible

Comment: Thats my fault I removed that whilst working on something else by accident. I thought this would work but it didn't, I think maybe due to how my navigation is nested, but this is unavoidable. The span radio icon does not change.

Comment: So instead of span you need radio buttons? Is that correct?

Comment: Not really, I'm using ionicons, they have a radio-on and radio-off style icon. I will add a picture to my question of what I have